# Не работает CONCAT_WS

Tags: php, mysqli

Нужно записывать **reply_id** в колонку **reply**. Если **reply_id** много, то они должны записываться через запятую.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, если колонка reply пустая, то запятая все равно записывается перед или после **reply_id** (зависит от расположения сепаратора в запросе). Использую такой запрос:

```
UPDATE post SET reply = CONCAT(reply, ',', '$reply_id') WHERE id='$answer_id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось. Оказалось, что для поля **reply** для значения по умолчанию, в БД, должно быть **NULL**. Тогда запрос из вопроса будет работать, а если не установлен **NULL**, тогда подойдет этот запрос:

```
UPDATE post SET reply = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM CONCAT_WS(',', reply, '$reply_id')) WHERE id='$answer_id'
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin исправил.

Comment: *Оказалось, что CONCAT_WS работает только при SELECT, при UPDATE он не работает.* Что за бред? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d210666621b0fcbae04cb900a19060cd

Comment: @Akina, подозреваю, что у него не null, а пустая строка. Тем не менее, утверждение про select действительно смахивает на бред. Есть вероятность, что БД сама пустую строку заменяет на null при записи в таблицу? И вообще, а где у тебя в коде объединение с пустым?

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, лол